# How to stop Python print command from echoing in Visual Studio Code

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

Each time i run a print command in `Visual Studio Code` i get a `">>>"` and an echo of my `print` command!, how can i stop this?, here is a image :
**My Code:**

```
print("hello world")
```

**Result :**
[image]

Comment: @kabanus I simply want the console shows a single string "hello world" i do not need the ">>> print("hello world")

Comment: I got that now, thanks. I am guessing the other commands are not echoed, only `print`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're running the print statement from the python interpreter, which means that when you run a line it will print the line, then (if applicable) the output the line produces.

If you're trying to use the print statement within a python script, you should install the [python extension for Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial), and use it to run the file containing your script.

Comment: I have used the "select interpreter" and i selected "Anaconda" as my interpretor, is this the reason for the echo ?, can i stop this?

Comment: How are you running the print command? Is it part of a file, or are you typing it into a prompt?

Comment: i looked for the simplest method to run the code, and i reached shift + enter, meaning i select all the codes and use shift + enter

Comment: The documentation for the python VSCode extension says to "Select one or more lines, then press Shift+Enter or right-click and select Run Selection/Line in Python Terminal. This command is very convenient for testing just a part of a file.". If you run in the python terminal it will echo (print) each line before executing. If you don't want this you should run the entire file with right click -> run python file in terminal

Comment: thanks to you i found the problem, it was indeed because i was running the code using "Shift + Enter" and not using "Run the python file in terminal"